# multiplicity of components in resolution of surface singularity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth compact algebraic surface, and $C=\bigcup E_i$ be a connected divisor where the $E_i$ are integral and the matrix $(E_i\cdot E_j)$ is negative definite. In the analytic category, Grauert's contraction criterion implies that there is a contraction $\pi:X\to X'$ where $\pi(E)=0\in X'$ is a singular point and $\pi$ is an isomorphism everywhere else. If, moreover, the resulting singularity is rational ($R^1\pi_{*}\mathcal{O}_X=0$), then $X'$ is a normal projective variety.

Question: When $X'$ is algebraic, is there any reason to believe that the scheme-theoretic fiber $\pi^{-1}(0)$ is reduced? (I doubt it.) Are there further conditions we can impose to guarantee this? Is the fiber over the singular point related to the fundamental cycle of the singularity of $X'$?

Comment: No, in general $\pi^{-1}(0)$ will not be reduced. For example, in the rational double point situation, if it is of $A_n$ type, the fiber is reduced, otherwise it is not, assuming minimal resolution. If it is not minimal, even this can fail for $A_n$ type.

Comment: I don't quite have the time, nor the knowledge, to give you a full answer, but these questions are discussed extensively by Miles Reid in different places, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9602006.pdf, especially section 4.6, as well as the old, in its time famous, and it seems recently typed and updated http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masda/surf/eG.ps